# How can I get all the `\begin{definition}...\end{definition}` blocks in a LaTeX file?

Tags: python, regex, parsing, python-3.x, latex

I just finished to write the summary for calculus in Latex.

The main problem now is that the files contains many things I don't really need now.

The .tex files contains many definitions and theorems that i need to study by heart.

The definitions have their own definition in the tex file, so any definition in the file will start with:

```
\begin{definition}
```

and ends with

```
\end{definition}
```

And the same for theorems.

I need to write something to take out whatever is inside the `\begin{}...\end{}`.

For example in a list called A:

```
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{definition} Hello WOrld! \end{definition}
\begin{example}A+B \end{example}
\begin{theorem} Tre Capre \end{theorem}
\begin{definition} Hello WOrld2! \end{definition}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

should contains :`[[\begin{definition} Hello WOrld! \end{definition}],[\begin{theorem} Tre Capre \end{theorem}],[\begin{definition} Hello WOrld2! \end{definition}]]`

Looking in this site i found that i can use Regular Expressions:

```
for i in range(5):
    x = i+1
    raw = open('tex/chapter' + str(x) + '.tex')
    A = []
    for line in raw:
        A.append(re.match(r'(\begin{definition})://.*\.(\end{definition})$', line))
print(A)
```

but the output is just `None` and I don't really know why.

Edit:

```
import re


for i in range(5):
    x = i+1
    raw = open('tex/chapter' + str(x) + '.tex')
    A = re.findall(r'\\begin{definition}(.*?)\\end{definition}', raw.read())
    print(A)
```

the output is the following:

```
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
```

Comment: I would hint you to a template processor lile Jinja2

Comment: Add the site reference, because it is not really clear what you are trying to achieve via `re.match(r'(\begin{definition})://.*\.(\end{definition})$', line)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract specific section from LaTeX file with python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39157084/5267751)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I get from the question you just want the definitions from the Latex file. You can use `findall` to directly get your definitions:

```
A = re.findall(r'{definition}(.*?)\\end{definition}', raw.read())
```

Note the usage to `.*?` in order to tackle the [greedy](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#greedy-versus-non-greedy) regex matching

Comment: @BioShock Did this work for you? Or do you want something else?

Comment: Actually it doesn't work! I mean, if i run the script with this line and i also add ``print(A)`` it just prints ``[ ]`` (empty list)

Comment: @BioShock What exactly is your input? Check the answer now. I guess the `\b` in your input is being wrongly interpreted

Comment: @BioShock did you check the new answer? It doesn't have a `\\begin`

Comment: Note that this answer doesn't handle the case this the definition spans multiple lines, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/39157185/5267751 for more details.

Answer (score 2):

While in this case the regular expression works well for most LaTeX files, for more complex tasks you should use a LaTeX parser library.

This one can be solved with `pylatexenc` like this:

```
from pylatexenc import latexwalker
from pylatexenc.latexwalker import LatexWalker, make_json_encoder
data="(LaTeX source code)"
def traverse(node: latexwalker.LatexNode)->None:
    if node.isNodeType(latexwalker.LatexEnvironmentNode):
        if node.environmentname=="definition":
            # Print the raw LaTeX of the whole node including the \begin{definition}
            print(node.latex_verbatim())
            # ... or without
            print("".join(x.latex_verbatim() for child in node.nodelist))
        for child in node.nodelist: traverse(child)
for node in LatexWalker(data).get_latex_nodes()[0]:
    traverse(node)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can let latex do the job, no need for external workarounds with python. Using the `extract` package, you can specify which environments you would like to extract and it will produce a second `.tex` file with the desired content.

Comment: To clarify: `extract` is a LaTeX package, not a Python package, and (I assume?) you have to modify the .tex file to add that command then invoke LaTeX from Python.

Comment: @user202729 You don't need python at all. Just add it to the preamble and you get a second tex file with all the definitions