# Extract specific section from LaTeX file with python

Tags: python, regex, latex

I have a set of LaTeX files. I would like to extract the "abstract" section for each one:

```tex
\begin{abstract}

.....

\end{abstract}
```

I have tried the suggestion here: [How to Parse LaTex file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30752351/how-to-parse-latex-file)

And tried :

```
A = re.findall(r'\\begin{abstract}(.*?)\\end{abstract}', data)
```

Where data contains the text from the LaTeX file. But `A` is just an empty list. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is `data` and how did you generate it? You possibly need the [`re.DOTALL`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.DOTALL) option to make the `.` able to match over newlines.

Comment: In this specific case you specifically want to parse it with regex (which might fail in some corner cases), but [there's a solution using a LaTeX parsing library for Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65950159/5267751).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`.*` does not match newlines unless the re.S flag is given:

```
re.findall(r'\\begin{abstract}(.*?)\\end{abstract}', data, re.S)
```

#### Example

Consider this test file:

```tex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}
Title maybe
\begin{abstract}
Good stuff
\end{abstract}
Other stuff
\end{document}
```

This gets the abstract:

```
>>> import re
>>> data = open('a.tex').read()
>>> re.findall(r'\\begin{abstract}(.*?)\\end{abstract}', data, re.S)
['\nGood stuff\n']
```

#### Documentation

From the [`re` module's webpage](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.DOTALL):

> re.S
>  re.DOTALL
>
> Make the '.' special character match any character at
>   all, including a newline; without this flag, '.' will match anything
>   except a newline.

Answer (score 4):

The `.` does not match newline character.  However, you can pass a flag to ask it to include newlines.

Example:

```
import re

s = r"""\begin{abstract}
this is a test of the
linebreak capture.
\end{abstract}"""

pattern = r'\\begin\{abstract\}(.*?)\\end\{abstract\}'

re.findall(pattern, s, re.DOTALL)

#output:
['\nthis is a test of the\nlinebreak capture.\n']
```